# frank.php templates

Tags: php, frameworks

happy to see a sinatra-like microframework in php
http://github.com/brucespang/Frank.php

but, documentation is scarce, and i'm not understading reading the code
(maybe i'm not able):

you can define a views directory

```
set(array('views' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates'));
```

but how you can render file inside it?

how passing parameters?

there is no templating, simple php?

bye

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the index.php file (I added comments myself):

```
// when you go to */template
get("/template", function(){
    // calls the template named "template" and passes variables to it
    render('template', array('locals' => array('name' => 'template'))); 
});

// setup the "template" named template
template("template", function($locals){
    echo 'Hello from '.$locals['name'];
});
```

It also says directly in the readme that it doesn't support any templating languages yet:

> What Frank.php is missing:
>
> 1. Spiffy template languages like haml and sass.template languages like haml and sass.

The framework looks far from complete, I probably wouldn't use it for anything essential.

Comment: if you create templates/test with some content and do render('test') it does display the content. but how i can pass vars to template?

Comment: You pass the variables to it as the 2nd parameter of render(), for example `render('test', array('vars' => array('var1' => 'answer1')))`.  Then you can call on that 'var1' by doing something similar to `$var['var1']` within the template.